How to fully and completely remove a menu defined by easy-menu-define
Given an example menu created via easy-menu:
(easy-menu-define my-example-menu-map java-mode-map "My example menu" `("ExampleMenu"
  ["Hello World" 'ignore]
  ; ... more items below
))

What is the proper way to completely remove it from the provided key map (in this example case java-mode-map)?
I have tried something like the following:
(define-key java-mode-map [menu-bar ExampleMenu] nil)

It doesn't work quite right since lingering (ExampleMenu) entry is left (i.e. checking via (lookup-key java-mode-map [menu-bar])).
Other variations just do not work because the keys likely don't exist or otherwise:
(define-key java-mode-map [ExampleMenu] nil)
(define-key java-mode-map [menu-bar] nil) ; Just completely eliminates the entire menu bar key which means any other menus defined in the map
(define-key java-mode-map [menu-bar my-example-menu-map] nil)
(define-key java-mode-map [my-example-menu-map] nil)

There must be something I am missing with how define-key is working for mode specific menus (normally in the global map, it works how I would expect IIRC). Otherwise, it must be something unique with how easy-menu-define actually constructs the menus and inserts them (the use of the menu's car as the interned symbol to put in the mode map is kind of strange but the effect is as above).
I looked into easy-menu-remove-item (since according to the documentation easy-menu-remove is an old function that doesn't actually do anything more for modern Emacs) but that didn't work either and I am not sure I would need to provide a path to it either.
Any advice, direction, or solutions are greatly appreciated!
NOTE: - To preempt anyone asking or flagging this as "duplicate": This is NOT a duplicate of How to remove menu with easymenu? since that question didn't actually get answered and instead used some hacky trickery to fake the desired result.
Standard environment disclosure:

OS: MacOS
Chip: Intel
Emacs Version: 27.2.1
Port: Mitsuharu Yamamoto / Railwaycat
Other Notes: - No special distributions / etc.
Relevant Common Packages Used:

Standard internal Emacs packages




Delete the (easy-menu-define ...) form from your init file and restart emacs: the menu will be gone. If you ran it by hand and never included it in your init file, just restart emacs.

@NickD Er, I am not sure if you are trying to be funny but I am going to assume not. I do indeed want to have the menu exist, I am not just arbitrarily adding easy-menu-define in my init.el file. I have functions that should be able to both add it and remove it. Adding it works as expected but removing it doesn't appear to work as expected. In my example, it's just for illustrative purposes to reproduce the issue. In my use case, I only want the menu under certain conditions and when those conditions are untrue, the menu should be removed (and re-added when they become true again).

Open a bug/RFE  with Emacs and ask that easy-menu-remove be actually implemented instead of being a no-op. I don't know how extensive the changes are that easy-menu-define makes, but it seems you want to remove all of them. All I can suggest is to read the code and start undoing, but you might miss some and you might end up in an inconsistent state. Next question (not meant to be funny either): why do you want to remove the menu? What is the problem with it being there?

BTW, if you do open an RFE, the "why" question is the first thing that you are going to be asked, so you might as well answer that question now and include your reasons in the RFE.

@NickD thanks for the suggestion. However, Emacs uses an archaic model for development (mailing lists) that I just cannot be asked to figure out how to use / work within. Nothing against it but it's just a barrier to contribution that I don't have time for. If the project was GitHub or somewhere, I might make an account and submit an issue/PR, but unfortunately that is not the case. I submitted my own answer below for posterity.

To address the question of "Why", I simply would say "Why not?". There should always be an option to remove menus after the fact, no matter what. It's a customization option the user may want, the context for the menu not always be current/correct for the major mode (e.g. a Java project that doesn't use Maven shouldn't have a Maven menu bar entry, for example), and the menu may be dynamic where the majority of the contents change that would be easier to just eject/inject it again versus manipulating it in place. All of these are very good reasons for such a behavior: removing a menu ad-hoc.

I am posting this here in case anyone else runs into the same problem or is just interested in learning. I solved this by using my older method for manipulating the menu bar (i.e. always maintain manual control over how the menu is injected). I think the root issue is how easy-menu manipulates a mode's map for menu items but this completely bypasses that.
(define-key (lookup-key java-mode [menu-bar]) [a_unique_key_fort_the_menu] nil) ; Ejects any previous version of the menu if it was declared in the following way
; Same as the prior declaration except instead of providing the `java-mode-map` to easy-menu, we will do it ourselves afterward to ensure it's properly injected
(easy-menu-define my-example-menu-map nil "My example menu" `("ExampleMenu"
  ["Hello World" 'ignore]
  ; ... more items below
))
(define-key java-mode-map [menu-bar a_unique_key_fort_the_menu] (cons "RealExampleMenuText" my-example-menu-map))

I decided that I really didn't want to spend the time unraveling easy-menu, it's not super tricky but just more work than I have time for at the moment. I would suggest first looking at how it's using the car of the menu as the symbol it appears to be storing the menu entry. Otherwise, using the above solution is more than adequate.
